# Input text at the bottom on IE10

Tags: html, css, input

Why is my input text rendered at the bottom of the input on IE10? FF and Chrome renders it in the middle as it's supposed to be.

http://jsfiddle.net/PXN2e/2/

```
input.form-text {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    width: 150px;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Please don't say that the only solution is by removing the `box-sizing: border-box;`, I actually need this. And removing it, the input box becomes too big anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `line-height` from  `input.form-text`

```
input.form-text {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    /*line-height: 30px;*/ /* Removed */
    padding: 6px 10px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PXN2e/4/)

Comment: Solved! And I read somewhere that I had to use line-height with height so it would align with the button in same line.

Comment: @OptimusPrime You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616618/height-vs-line-height-styling) as a ref :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving a `line-height`, then remove the top/bottom padding:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/PXN2e/7/***

*CSS*:

```
input.form-text {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 10px; /* <-- Remove top/bottom padding */
    width: 150px;
}
```

`line-height` will vertically align to the `height` if specified. So, adding extra padding may cause such problems. Moreover, you don't have to carefully calc the top/bottom padding to vertically align.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your line-height but just reconsile with the padding you added:

30px - 6px -6px = 18px

```
line-height: 18px
```