# Difference between height and line-height, using rem

Tags: css, height, line-height

Im writing CSS:

```
.block1 {line-height:1.2rem} 
.block2 {height:1.2rem}
```

Calculated sizes in browser:
block1 height = 19px and
block2 height = 19.2px

Where does the difference come from? How i can get same size using rem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [height vs line-height styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616618/height-vs-line-height-styling)

Comment: What are you using to calculate the heights?

Comment: I watch it in the Chrome developer tools. Ctrl+shift+i.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is rounding. When Chrome calculating line-height, it becomes 19. And the real value is 19.2.